# Kivy: set widget disabled property in python code

Tags: python, widget, kivy, bind

I have something like this in kivy lang file (pseudo code)

```
<RootWidget>:
    Checkbox:
        id: chkbox
    TextInput:
        id: in_text
        text: ""
    Button:
        id: ok_btn 
        label: "Okay"
        on_press: app.ok_pressed()
        disabled: chkbox.active or len(in_text.text) > 8 and ...
```

The point is, the ok_btn needs to be enabled and disabled dynamically based on state of several other widgets.

This all works as expected, but now I have a problem. For complicated reasons, I need to create the button and insert it into the root widget in python rather than define it in a .kv file or string. I can't figure out what to do with the disabled property. If I set it as a property

```
btn = Button()
btn.disabled = ...
```

This only sets the initial state. I thought maybe

```
btn.bind(on_disabled=some_function)
```

but this is only to do something when the button is disabled, not to define when it should be disabled. Ditto on_state. I also tried

```
btn.bind(disabled=some_function)
```

some_function is never called

Thanks in advance for any pointer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have it backwards: it isn't the button's disabled property that you want to bind things to, but rather you want to bind to *other* things so that when they change the button's disabled property gets updated.

For instance, from your original example the autogenerated code is along the lines of `chkbox.bind(active=lambda self: setattr(ok_btn, "disabled", self.active)` (not actually this code, but something equivalent). You need to replicate this manually.

Of course you can abstract this in various ways. For instance, you could bind all the conditions you care about to update a property of your App class (so that it's always present to update, regardless of whether your button exists), then use a kv rule like `disabled: app.that_property` in your button. This is not the only option though.